# Line spacing doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change line spacing for my `textLabel` in storyboard. I select `text` -> `attributed` and change paragraph `line` to 1. If I use `textLabel` in storyboard everything works fine. But If I connect `textLabel` in storyboard with my `ViewController`, this line spacing doesn't work. How to fix it?

My code:

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let questions : [Question]
}

struct Question : Decodable {
    let number, text, rightAnswer : String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var questions = [Question]()
    @IBOutlet var textLabel: UILabel!

    func updateUI(with question: Question) {
        title = question.number
        textLabel.text = question.text
        showAnswerLabel.text = question.rightAnswer
    }


}
```

Comment: `textLabel.text = question.text` You are not setting the `attributedText` there.

Comment: @Larme I didn't want to do this programmatically. I thought that I could do this in my storyboard.

Comment: At runtime can you print the textLabel to see if it is hooked on to the storyboard correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplished that by using a lazy var and some property observers. Configure the text styles the way you want in Interface Builder and use this code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    lazy var defaultAttributes = textLabel.attributedText!.attributes(at: 0, effectiveRange: nil)
    var questionText: String {
        get { return textLabel.text! }
        set { textLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: newValue, attributes: defaultAttributes) }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionText = "What are the color of yellow cab taxi in New York City?"
    }
}
```

Notce that we did not touch `textLabel` directly to change its text. We do so via the computed property `questionText`.

Result:

[image: sample UILabel]